# Excel Match function value changes return #CALC

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Function as follows -

```
=TEXTJOIN(", "; TRUE;UNIQUE(FILTER(DROP(Sheet1!$G:$G;MATCH(1; Sheet1!$A:$A; 0) -1); DROP(Sheet1!C:C;MATCH(1; Sheet1!$A:$A; 0) -1) = Details!$BI$16)))
```

It works perfectly till the moment I change MATCH(1; Sheet1!$A:$A; 0) -1) value 1 in cell A5. Its important in my case, because I want to provide end value in case user make some changes in first row (delete row). So I decided to use MATCH to find exact location on first cell in column A which contains value 1. What could be the reason?

Comment: Is that in the same sheet/column? Please add an example of when it works and when it doesn't.

Comment: Most likely FILTER isn't returning any results, which would then cause a CALC error, since you didn't supply the last argument.

Comment: The Sheet1!$A:$A is different Sheet. I run this function in Detailes Sheet. It works when Sheet1 A5=1, when i move value 1 to any other cell - it returns #CALC. Althou if i run just MATCH(1; Sheet1!$A:$A; 0) -1, it returns the cell row no matter where I move the 1.

Comment: I see that in function part UNIQUE(FILTER(DROP(Sheet1!$G:$G;MATCH(1; Sheet1!$A:$A;0)-1 );DROP(Sheet1!C:C; MATCH(1; Sheet1!$A:$A;0)-1) = Details!$BI$16)) is returning #VALUE